# AngularJS - dynamic naming using $index in expression

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-form

I have a directive in which i create many `ng-form`'s and i name each form based on the `$index` (from the `ng-repeat`). My problem is that i want to show an error container (that contains the error message) when the **form** is invalid but i cant find how to properly reference the form.

Here is my code:

```
<ng-form name="innerForm{{$index}}">

    <label ... ><input name="input" ... />

        <div class="error-container" ng-show="'innerForm'+$index.input.$invalid">
               // show the error message
        </div>

</ng-form>
```

I want `'innerForm'+$index.input.$invalid` to be evaluated as `innerForm5.input.$invalid` for example.

I have made many attempts but i can't get it to work. What is the correct way to reference my dynamically named form?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

please see here : http://jsbin.com/jocane/4/edit

```
 <div ng-controller="firstCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="object in allMyObjects">
    <ng-form name="innerForm{{$index}}">
  <input type="text"  ng-model="object.name" required name="userName">

      <div ng-show="{{'innerForm'+$index}}.userName.$invalid">
               error
        </div>
      </form>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing is that, ng-form creates an isolated scope. So if you give a ng-form static name, it will be ok. No need to append $index or anything.

```
ng-show="innerForm.input.$invalid"
```

Code snippet to find form controller using element

```
  var elmParent = $(domEle).parents('form, ng-form, [ng-form]');
    var formCtrl = null;
    var elemCtrl = null;
    if (elmParent.length) {
    var elm = angular.element(domEle);
        formCtrl = elm.scope().$parent[elmParent.attr('name') || elmParent.attr('ng-form')];
    }
```

Hope this will help

Comment: i know it and the reason i do it like that is because i want to reference it externally.

Comment: then my friend, you can not do that. For all item ng-form name will be same (without compiled). Though You can access parent ng-form from element scope. Then you can do your validation on that.

Comment: Added a code to find ng-from or form form dom element hope it will help